# Grub error wrong uuid

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, grub

I've installed archlinux with GRUB but the uuid that appears in GRUB when boots is different to /etc/fstab.

I did this:

```
arch-root /mnt
grub-install --efi-directory=boot/efi /dev/sda
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
mkinitcpio -p linux
```

In /boot/grub/grub.cfg only appears the correct UUID (the same that fstab). It's ok.

Why in menu GRUB appears a UUID different? How I can change it?

Comment: It might be useful to be specific what UUID you checked.  Typically grub.cfg will contain one UUID used in the process of finding the kernel, then a UUID passed to the kernel+initramfs (`root=` option).  If `/boot` is not a separate filesystem, the two UUIDs will have the same value.

Comment: Exactly, I tryied it that in this moment. That is the problem. Thank you and sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was --efi-directory, it must be the same that grub-mkconfig

```
arch-root /mnt
grub-install --efi-directory=boot /dev/sda
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
mkinitcpio -p linux
```

Solved.